# Bootstrap Column - Position Relative and Z Index

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an element that has a fixed position to the bottom left corner of the browser window. I noticed that the text in footer layers above the fixed position element.

I traced this back to the Bootstrap style for columns that sets them to a relative position. If I remove or override that style, the layering appears as I desire. I don't, however, know why that style is there. I am concerned over unintended side-effects.

Why does Bootstrap use `position: relative` in their column class?

I'm also open to other ways of accomplishing my desired layering without changing core Bootstrap styles.

---

**EDIT**

When creating a minimal example, I found that the issue was not present. I then looked to my own CSS for the problem. I found that it was `z-index: 0` on the element containing the fixed position element that was the culprit. Changing it to `z-index: 1` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a class to the element that you want to change then overwrite the Bootstrap styles with the new class.

It is difficult to guess without a code example, but something like:

```
<footer><p class="override-bootstrap">Some text</p></footer>
```

CSS

```
.override-bootstrap {
  // here reset the styles
}
```

Make  sure that the stylesheet for your new class is included after the bootstrap css.

Comment: I know how to override styles. I'm concerned about overriding this style because don't know why it's there.

Comment: If you use it only in the specific element you want then you should be able to control why it's there.

Comment: A concrete code example would be helpful.

Comment: Your suggestion for a code example got me creating a minimal example. When creating a minimal example, I found that the issue is not present. I found that it was the setting a z-index of a containing element to zero that caused my layering problems. I'm going to upvote some of your other answers, and delete this question.

Comment: Glad you found the problem

Comment: I can't delete the question, I guess. How embarrassing.